# Is there an efficient way to retrieve frames from a video in Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have an app which requires me to retrieve frames from a video and do some processing with them.  However it seems like that the frame retrieval is very slow to the point where it is unacceptable. Sometimes it is taking upto 2.5 second to retrieve a single frame. I am using the [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) as most stackoverflow questions suggested. However the performance is very bad. Here is what I have:

```
   private List<Bitmap> retrieveFrames() {

        MediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        fmmr.setDataSource("/path/to/some/video.mp4");
        String strLength = fmmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long milliSecs = Long.parseLong(strLength);
        long microSecLength = milliSecs * 1000;

        Log.d("TAG", "length: " + microSecLength);
        long one_sec = 1000000; // one sec in micro seconds

        ArrayList<Bitmap> frames = new ArrayList<>();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < microSecLength; i += (one_sec / 5)) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Bitmap frame = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
            j++;
            Log.d("TAG", "Frame number: " + j + " Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            // commented out because each frame would be written to disk instead of holding them in memory
            //  frames.add(frame);
        }
        fmmr.release();
        return frames;
    }
```

The above will logs:

```
03-26 21:49:29.781  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ length: 4949000
03-26 21:49:30.187  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 1 Time taken: 406
03-26 21:49:30.779  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 2 Time taken: 592
03-26 21:49:31.578  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 3 Time taken: 799
03-26 21:49:32.632  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 4 Time taken: 1054
03-26 21:49:33.895  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 5 Time taken: 1262
03-26 21:49:35.382  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 6 Time taken: 1486
03-26 21:49:37.128  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 7 Time taken: 1746
03-26 21:49:39.077  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 8 Time taken: 1948
03-26 21:49:41.287  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 9 Time taken: 2210
03-26 21:49:43.717  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 10 Time taken: 2429
03-26 21:49:44.093  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 11 Time taken: 376
03-26 21:49:44.707  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 12 Time taken: 614
03-26 21:49:45.539  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 13 Time taken: 831
03-26 21:49:46.597  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 14 Time taken: 1057
03-26 21:49:47.875  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 15 Time taken: 1278
03-26 21:49:49.384  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 16 Time taken: 1508
03-26 21:49:51.112  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 17 Time taken: 1728
03-26 21:49:53.096  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 18 Time taken: 1983
03-26 21:49:55.315  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 19 Time taken: 2218
03-26 21:49:57.711  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 20 Time taken: 2396
03-26 21:49:58.065  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 21 Time taken: 354
03-26 21:49:58.640  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 22 Time taken: 574
03-26 21:49:59.369  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 23 Time taken: 728
03-26 21:50:00.112  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 24 Time taken: 742
03-26 21:50:00.834  13213-13239/com.example.naveed.myapplication D/TAG﹕ Frame number: 25 Time taken: 721
```

As you can see from above, it is taking about 18 - 25 sec to retrieve 25 frames from a 4 sec long video.

I have also tried [this](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) which uses FFmpeg underneath to do the same.  I am not sure how well this library is implemented but it only improves the over all performance by a couple of seconds meaning it takes about 15-20 sec to do the same.

So my question is: is there a way to do it quicker?  My friend has an iOS app where he does something similar but it only takes couple of seconds and he is grabbing even more frames however he is not sure how to do it on android.

Is there anything on android that would speed up the process.  Am I approaching this wrong?

The end goal is to stitch those frames together into a gif.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC instead of OPTION_CLOSEST which might speed this up a little, but this will get the closest keyframe int the video. I don't know if there is any way to speed this up on android.

Comment: I have tried OPTION_CLOSET_SYNC before but the frames retrieved are really inaccurate and most are duplicates.  The the end result (gif) looks very bad.